# Is there a better way to "link" text inputs?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have the input boxes linked so that when you type something in one, it shows up in the other (and vice versa). Here's a "codepen" that shows how I'm doing it currently.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yEAbk/

It's pretty simple, but I feel like there should be an easier way to accomplish this. There is also a problem with this method that I illustrated in the codepen. You'll notice the button that fills one of the boxes with a string. Even though the content has been changed, the "onchange" event doesn't run, and so the other input box is not updated.

Is there an easier way to do this that will fix the problems I've been having?

Comment: it is working fine, and also the code is quite short and simple

Comment: The onchange event only fires on user input and you should be glad. You usually do not want events firing when your code sets an input, only when the user does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly the kind of problem `databinding` is meant to solve. There are lots of libraries out there, but the most popular currently is AngularJS (by google). http://angularjs.org/

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/34ZCs/2/ both inputs are bound to variable `yourName`:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div>    
        <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="A">
        <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="B">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With angular, you can accomplish with zero lines of custom JavaScript. You can accomplish it with just your view, as illustrated above. Very cool!

Comment: This is great. As you've probably guessed, I'm really new to this. I didn't even know what a library was until now, so I'm not really sure what's going on in your code or how to get it to work (outside of jsfiddle)... Do I have to download AngularJS?

Answer (score 0):

Use "onkeyup" instead of "onchange". Then the next textbox will be updated instantly.

Do something like this

```
<input type="text" name="a" id="a" onkeyup="fillBoth('a','b')" onfocus="fillBoth('a','b')" />
<input type="text" name="b" id="b" onkeyup="fillBoth('b','a')"
onfocus="fillBoth('a','b')"/>
<button type="button" id="clicky" onclick="fillWithX()">click here for xxx</button>
```

And you JavaScript should be updated like this.

```
function fillWithX() {
    document.getElementById('a').value = 'xxx';
  document.getElementById('a').focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight change in your event handler might do the trick. Take a look: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/budnp/

```
<input type="text" name="a" id="a" onchange="fillBoth('b', 'a');" />
<input type="text" name="b" id="b" onchange="fillBoth('a', 'b');" />
<button type="button" id="clicky" onclick="fillWithX()">click here for xxx</button>
```

and the script:

```
function fillBoth(copyTo, copyFrom) {
    document.getElementById(copyTo).value = document.getElementById(copyFrom).value;
}
```